# Mysql: obtaining two columns with different value from one column with redundant id

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns

maybe this is a stupid question but It's my first step in mysql
enviroment...

I got a table like this

```
Id|   Name|   Objects|      Class|
1      A         5            1
2      B         10           1
3      C         21           1
4      D         6            1
5      A         10           2
6      B         18           2
7      C         7            2
8      E         65           2

I would like to have a table in php like this:

|Id|    |Name|   |Objects when Class1|   |Objects when Class2|
  1      A              5                               10
  2      B              10                              18
  3      C              21                              7
  4      D              6                               0
```

and so on....

My problem is that the in the column Name I have some elements with the same
name, but with different number of objects when considering different classes.

So, which is the query in Mysql to obtain on the same row different values coming from the same column but that can differ when there are more than one classes?
I hope it was clear, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT Id,Name,`Objects when Class1`,`Objects when Class2`
FROM (
SELECT Id , Name , 
IFNULL( max(CASE WHEN class = 1 THEN objects END ),0) AS `Objects when Class1` ,
IFNULL( max(CASE WHEN class = 2 THEN objects END ),0) AS `Objects when Class2`
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
   )t
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51a9d/10)